# ESRI: dynamically hide features from web map

Tags: esri, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to implement this function with ArcGIS Server JavaScript API:

I have a web map created by ArcGIS Online (or a web map created on the fly using JSON). Within the web map, I have a point feature layer (or MapServer layer). Initially the entire layer is shown on the map.

Now I am receiving a list of feature IDs received from another server, and I need to hide those points with the feature IDs on the map whilst maintaining the visibility of other points.

I am receiving the lists of feature IDs every 5 mins. Once a new set of IDs is received, I need to make the corresponding point invisible. If a previously hidden point is not included in the new list, they need to be turned back on again on the map.

Any ideas on how to startthis?

Thank you!!

Eric

Comment: This is probably too broad to get a good Answer. Basically you need to implement a definition query -- you should take a look at some of the API samples ([e.g.](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/map_multiplelayerdef.html)) and then come back with a more focused request/problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you are trying to implement an AVL system.
Anyway, the best way for receiving data for another server is using AJAX. Then, every time you receive new points, you'll need to clear the feature layer point and then to add the newest information from the server.
If you put your code in a fiddle, I'll help you.

Rafael

Comment: Hi Rafael, actually I solved it by using select & hide, a relatively simple technique. Another way is to change the layer definition is layer info.